Telegram Message AutoForward using Python
I am trying to auto-forward a message from one group to another group of telegram using python. Currently this works when i run this. It forwards the last message from group A to group B. Need help with creating a loop wherein this works automatically. Whenever there is a new message which comes in Group A, it should get forwarded to Group B
api_id   =  123456
api_hash = '5ad488f'
source_chat_id = -1000000000  
destination_chat_id = -10000000000
with TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    chat = client.get_entity(source_chat_id)
    
    last_message_id = (client.get_messages(source_chat_id, limit=1))[0].id
    print(last_message_id)

    message = client.iter_messages(chat, limit=1)
    for message in client.get_messages(source_chat_id, limit=1):
        if message.id == last_message_id:
            client.send_message(destination_chat_id, message.text)
            print("Message forwarded")
            last_message_id = max(last_message_id, message.id)


What difficulty do you have with creating a loop?

You should listen to incoming message updates.
